# Get response from URL

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have the follow JS code to get the response from an URL. My URL it's ok, I got the response that I want to show, but I don't know how to show the response in JSON format. I'll appreciate any help.

```
var id = '84337255-f472-4630-986d-487f22009536';
var startDate = '2017-01-01';
var endDate = '2017-03-30';

var url = 'http://34.209.24.195/facturas\?id\=' + id + '\&start\=' + startDate + '\&finish\=' + endDate;

var urlRequestTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Failed to load resources");
}, 8000);

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "json",
  method: "GET",
  success : function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    clearTimeout(urlRequestTimeout);
  }
});
```

Comment: You have already used `console.log` which prints the JSON in browser console. Do you want to show the result in DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chrome console to view the response you are printing. Without seeing what the output is, I can only make a guess.

I would do something like this

```
let jsonObj = {}; //create empty JSON variable

$.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: "json",
      method: "GET",
      success : function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        jsonObj = response.data; //set the variable to the response data
        clearTimeout(urlRequestTimeout);
      }
    });
```

Now you have the response saved, and you can do with it what you want. If you want a more specific answer, you'll have to post your response output.

Or, as others have suggested. You can convert the value to a JSON string like such:

```
let jsonObj = JSON.stringify(response.data)
console.log(jsonObj);
```

Comment: This is the output that I'm getting: [response](http://imgur.com/a/eFzxY)

Comment: No, the correct response must be "Hay más de 100 resultados", or "Faltan parámetros", or the total of invoices for that id. This is the [link](http://34.209.24.195/facturas?id=84337255-f472-4630-986d-487f22009536&start=2017-01-01&finish=2017-03-30) with one of the correct outputs

Comment: @ArCiGo In your post you said you were getting the correct response, if that's not the case, I would suggest going back and looking through your request to make sure everything is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
```

instead of

```
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you received is a json format.

I think there are methods to resolve
1. `JSON.parse()`
2. `eval("(" + response + ")")`
but the second method will run code in the json.(not safe)

```
json format:var data='{
    "student" : [
        {"name":"A","age":17}, 
        {"name":"B","age":17},
        {"name":"C","age":17}
    ]
}'

eval('(' + data + ')');//jsonString->jsonObject
JSON.parse(data);//jsonString->jsonObject
```